# PHP-MYSQL Cannot delete on mysqli_multi_query

Tags: php, mysqli

I have two querys that have to delete rows on different tables when a checkbox is checked. The problem is that only executes one of the querys and ignores the other one.

Here's the code:

```
if(isset($_POST["che".$i.""])){
        $query4  = "DELETE FROM gastos WHERE id_dedicaciondos = $idded AND id_usuario=$idu;";
        $query4 .= "DELETE FROM dedicacio WHERE id_dedicacion = $idded AND id_usuario=$idu;" ;
        if(mysqli_multi_query($connexio,$query4)){
                  do{
                    if ($result = mysqli_store_result($connexio)) {
                        mysqli_free_result($result);
                    }

                }while(mysqli_next_result($connexio) && mysqli_more_results($connexio));
            }
    }
```

Only deletes the rows from the second query... If I change the order of the querys the result is exactly the same, only deletes from the query "delete from dedicacio".

What can I do?

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

I've tried the next:

```
if(isset($_POST["che".$i.""])){
        $query4  = "DELETE FROM gastos WHERE id_dedicaciondos = ".$idded.";";
       $query5 =  "DELETE FROM dedicacio WHERE id_dedicacion = ".$idded.";";

       if(mysqli_query($connexio,$query4)){
            echo "YES!";
       }
       if(mysqli_query($connexio,$query5)){
            echo "YES2!";
       }
    }
```

It shows "YES!" and "YES2!" But the query don't delete anything on the "gastos" table :(

*UPDATE*

I solved by myself adding a "ON DELETE CASCADE" to the id_dedicaciondos that references id_dedicacions.

Comment: try to see if you have a typo in the name of the columns. Also you can echo the query and see what is in there and try to run it manualy, for example in phpmyadmin, and see what happens then.

Comment: When I run it manually the query, it works... I've tried on mysql console and phpmyadmin. If I echo the query it returns what I expect, all is correct:

DELETE FROM gastos WHERE id_dedicaciondos = 1 AND id_usuario=1;DELETE FROM dedicacio WHERE id_dedicacion = 1 AND id_usuario=1;

Answer (score 0):

TRy to use this code:

```
if ($mysqli->multi_query($query4)) {
    do {
       if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
            $result->free();
        }
        /* print divider */
        if ($mysqli->more_results()) {
            printf("-----------------\n");
        }
    } while ($mysqli->next_result());
}
```

Comment: I get " Undefined variable: mysqli in..."

Comment: $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "testdb");

Comment: I get:

 "Strict standards: mysqli::next_result(): There is no next result set. Please, call mysqli_more_results()/mysqli::more_results() to check whether to call this function/method in H:\wamp\www\dedicacio\actuhores2.php on line 67"

And only deletes from the "dedicacio" table...

Comment: do a little change. remove the semi colon from the second query. its just a hit and trial method. because it execute the next queries if we placed a semi-colon.

Comment: It's impossible... I tried "DELETE dedicacio,gastos FROM dedicacio LEFT JOIN gastos ON dedicacio.id_dedicacion = gastos.id_dedicaciondos WHERE dedicacio.id_dedicacion = 22;" on the MySQL console and it works but on the php no... This is annoying :(

Comment: can you share the structure of you tables?

Comment: table dedicacion: http://oi44.tinypic.com/15z61i0.jpg
table gastos: http://oi41.tinypic.com/iwssh3.jpg

Comment: Can someone help with this please?

Comment: that "Strict Standards" response is asking for a change in the do-while condition.  Use `while ($mysqli->next_result() && $mysqli->more_results());` And cut out that copy/pasted divider section.

Answer (score 0):

Just tested this and it works fine:

```
<?php

    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "testdb"); 

    $query4 = "DELETE FROM test_table1 WHERE num = 0;";
    $query4 .= "DELETE FROM test_table2 WHERE num = 0;";

    $mysqli->multi_query($query4); 
    while ($mysqli->next_result()) {;} // flush queries

    $mysqli->close();

?>
```

Comment: It's strange... Only works with one of the queries... if(isset($_POST["che".$i.""])){ $query4 = "DELETE FROM gastos WHERE id_dedicaciondos = $idded AND id_usuario=$idu;"; $query4 .= "DELETE FROM dedicacio WHERE id_dedicacion = $idded AND id_usuario=$idu;" ; $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","user","password","database"); $mysqli->multi_query($query4); while ($mysqli->next_result()) {;} $mysqli->close(); }

Comment: Try echoing mysqli error in the while statement to see what's going on.